# sata cable with a clip

Tags: sata, computer-building, cable

What's the difference between a sata cable that does have a clip and one that does not have that clip?

The cable with a clip:

[image]

Comment: Without going into details, I would say the main difference is - the clip. ;)

Comment: +1. Thank goodness you didn't make this an answer or some self appointed police would have been sure to vote you down for humour.

Regards,

Comment: @Xavierjazz - yeah, sorry about that. I know it's not a very smart comment, but I couldn't resist, expecially how the question was put :)

Comment: I LOVE THE CLIP!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people like clips, some people don't. If you have to move drives a lot, it helps make sure you don't accidentally pull the connection with the motherboard loose.

It's purely a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in terms of tech specs, but the cables without clips can come disconnected easily with the slightest bump when you're working inside the computer, even if you're not working on the disks.